# Forge Viewer : Getting Textutes load Error While loading a 2d(.f2d) files using Viewer.loadModel method

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am using Autodesk forge viewer 7.2.0 version and trying to load a 2d(.f2d) Model files . I see the model is been loaded in browser , but while i am trying to load the model in ios devices , i am getting the error as shown in the image of this link [https://i.stack.imgur.com/eR1Fy.png] because of which the drawing is not loading completely.

Here is the snippet which we were using to load a .f2d files using Viewer API

viewer.loadModel(decodeURI(.f2d url), {globalOffset: {x: 0, y: 0, z: 0}, modelNameOverride: 'zcb'}, () => {}, (aErrorCode) => {});

Comment: Safari or other iOS browser? What version? Sounds like the it loads fine on other devices? Can you send the drawing to forge.help@autodesk.com (via GDrive/dropbox/weTransfer etc) so we can try to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Hi Bryan , sorry i  forgot to mention that we were loading the model in a ios hybrid app which will  internally use in app browser using cordova plugin to load the model in the browser . So here it is safari browser only . I will try to send you the sample drawing to you in the mean time .

Comment: Hi Bryan , i have sent you the sample model to the mentioned email.

Comment: Thanks for the files but it looks like an entire project rather than the model file and I've got no problems loading the model in `Resource` folder with Viewer v7.4 and iOS 13 - see screenshots [here](https://imgur.com/S3CgPYC) and [here](https://imgur.com/N0qB9e4) - did I miss anything or ?

Comment: Sorry for late response , we were facing the issues while loading the .f2d files not the svf files . so can you please try loading the .f2d file which is in this 1da56fb7-92fd-28b1-a914-9754b5d80ed0_f2d  folder inside the main folder .

Answer (score 0):

Is this the offending f2d? Still couldn't reproduce the issue though (Viewer v7/iOS 13):

[image]
[image]

What's your iOS/Safari/Viewer version and is there anything else to you code that might cause the errors? Any functionality affected?

Comment: I am facing the same issue with all the .f2d files which are there in that folder.Ios version is 12.4.2 and i have tested on viewer versions 7.3.0 and 7.4.0 . The issue is i couldn't see the complete model loaded . Please see this picture . When  i see the debug console logs , i found the error which i have shared in the initial question .

Comment: Here is the url of the screen shot which i mentioned in the above comment [https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zAxC.jpg]

Comment: I personally don't have a iOS 12.4.2 device to replicate the issue (since it's not exactly possible to roll back to 12) so I am going to escalate this to Engineering and see if they could reproduce this - will let you know when I hear back.